# Read excel cell styling and formatting in C#

Tags: c#, excel, sharepoint, openxml, export-to-excel

I have an excel file located on SharePoint. I am reading the excel file in C# using OpenXML. While reading the data, I also need the information of any styles that are been added to the cells.

If there is any cell that has been added a background color to, How can I read it in C# ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this you will find some references about foreground color and background color of cell
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c46f8610-0394-4eb9-a0f4-3d9a569817f0/other-properties-of-cell?forum=oxmlsdk

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how you can do that with OpenXML, in the past i have always used  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. It's a nuget package that allow you to manipulate your excel style.

[image: Nuget Package]

I hope it can help you!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).